# How to to check array index element exists or not

Tags: postgresql

I am trying  to check array index element exists or not.

clmdata[atrindx] it is giving  NULL.

**PostgreSQL  code.**

```
do $$
begin 
   CREATE DOMAIN vararraytype AS numeric(9)[];
END$$;

do $$
begin
create type custschema.coldata_r as (sno numeric, cname varchar, dids integer, dloc varchar2);
END $$;

do $$
begin
create domain custschema.coldata as coldata_r[];
END $$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION custschema.upds_func(
p_indarray vararraytype)
RETURNS void AS
$body$
    declare
        v_col_array      custschema.colrectab;
        v_columnRec        custschema.colrec;
        rec record;
        clmdata custschema.coldata; 
begin
for rec in (select sno,cname,dids,dloc from customer where custid='CUST12')
                  loop
                    clmdata[rec.sno]:=rec;
                    raise info ' clmdata[rec.sno] %',clmdata[rec.sno];
                  end loop;
raise info 'p_indarray %',array_length(p_indarray,1);
for x IN 1 .. coalesce(array_length(p_indarray,1),0) 
loop
v_columnRec.colIndex := p_indarray[x] + 2;
raise info 'v_columnRec.colIndex %',v_columnRec.colIndex;

perform custschema.arrayindex(v_columnRec.colIndex)

v_col_array[x] := v_columnRec;
end loop;
end $body$ language plpgsql;

Output of raise info  from "custschema.upds_func" function.
raise info ' clmdata[rec.sno] %',clmdata[rec.sno];

clmdata[rec.sno] (1,Abi,15,Hyd)
clmdata[rec.sno] (2,Jhon,15,Mum)
clmdata[rec.sno] (3,Thomas,20,Bang)
clmdata[rec.sno] (4,Marry,25,SYD)
clmdata[rec.sno] (5,Tina,7,KCP)
clmdata[rec.sno] (6,Jorge,10,LOL)
clmdata[rec.sno] (7,Michal,15,CHE)
clmdata[rec.sno] (8,Chanu,9,USA)

raise info 'p_indarray %',array_length(p_indarray,1); -- O/P 3
raise info 'v_columnRec.colIndex %',v_columnRec.colIndex; -- O/P 3


create or replace  function custschema.arrayindex(atrindx  IN NUMERIC,cname   out VARCHAR) AS
$body$
declare 
clmdata custschema.coldata;
begin
raise info 'atrindx %',atrindx;
raise info 'sno %',clmdata[attrIndex].sno;
if clmdata[atrindx].sno IS NULL then
raise exception e'%',  'invalid index';
end if;
cname := clmdata[atrindx].col_nme;
end $body$ language plpgsql;

Output of raise info  from "custschema.arrayindex" function.
raise info 'atrindx %',atrindx;  --O/P 3
raise info 'sno %',clmdata[attrIndex].sno; -- O/P NULL
```

Raising the exception "invalid index".

**Oracle code.**

```
procedure arrayindex(atrindx  IN integer,cname   OUT varchar2) 
is
v_sno integer;
begin
dbms_output.put_line('atrindx' ||atrindx);
v_sno:=clmdata(attrIndex).sno;
dbms_output.put_line('v_sno'||v_sno );
if (not clmdata.exists(atrindx)) then  
gnvGen.toStr(attrIndex-2));
raise ind_excetion;
end if;
cname := clmdata(atrindx).col_nme;
end;

dbms_output.put_line('atrindx' ||atrindx); -- O/P 3
dbms_output.put_line('v_sno'||v_sno );
v_sno 3
v_sno 4
v_sno 5
```

In Oracle `v_sno:=clmdata(attrIndex).sno;` gives data as 3,4,5.

Whereas in PostgreSQL  `v_sno:=clmdata(attrIndex).sno;` gives NULL.

My expectation is  whatever the values are setting for clmdata[rec.sno]:=rec in the "custschema.upds_func"  function.
It should be carry forwarded to custschema.arrayindex function.

```
for rec in (select sno,col_nme,dids,dloc from customer where custid='CUST12')
                  loop
                    clmdata[rec.sno]:=rec;
                    raise info ' clmdata[rec.sno] %',clmdata[rec.sno];
                  end loop;

raise info ' clmdata[rec.sno] %',clmdata[rec.sno];

clmdata[rec.sno] (1,Abi,15,Hyd)
clmdata[rec.sno] (2,Jhon,15,Mum)
clmdata[rec.sno] (3,Thomas,20,Bang)
clmdata[rec.sno] (4,Marry,25,SYD)
clmdata[rec.sno] (5,Tina,7,KCP)
clmdata[rec.sno] (6,Jorge,10,LOL)
clmdata[rec.sno] (7,Michal,15,CHE)
clmdata[rec.sno] (8,Chanu,9,USA)
```

I tried what you suggested it is just skipping the error

```
.
But not assigning values to "cname" variable. 

if cardinality(clmdata) < atrindx then
raise exception e'%',  'invalid index';
end if;
cname := clmdata[atrindx].col_nme;
raise info  'cname %',col_name; -- This is printing null.

It should print  col_nme as below.
Thomas
Marry
Tina
```

Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated, but: there is no need to putt each `CREATE` statement into a `do` block And the domains are pretty useless in my opinion, especially `vararraytype`

Comment: I think you are looking for `if cardinality(clmdata) < atrindx then ...`

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what this code is supposed to to. The whole code seems **way** to complicated for (as far as I can tell) something that simply loops over an array. You are never initializing any of your (e.g. `clmdata`  or `v_col_array`) to any access to it will always yield `null` And the for loop to put data into that array isn't necessary to begin with as you can simply use `select array_agg(...) into clmdata from customer ...`. The function `arrayindex` is defined to accept two parameters, but you are only calling it with one, so that won't work anyway.

Comment: I am specipically looking for 

if clmdata[atrindx].sno 
This is giving null.

Thanks.

Comment: I think it would be better if you described the underlying problem this (extremely hard to understand) code is trying to solve, rather than throwing some wall of code at us. But if you want to check if `attrindx` is is out of the range for the given array, then `if cardinality(clmdata) < atrindx then` is the way go go. But you should **really** try to simplify this for Postgres. That code is **way** too complicated and I am very sure this can be massively simplified (probably in Oracle as well, but definitely in Postgres)

Comment: I tried what you suggested it is just skipping the error
.But not assigning values to "cname" variable. I have edited my question. please help me.